# Cannot copy a large file; space available

Tags: ssd, error, copy-paste, file-transfer

Trying to copy (drag and drop) an ISO file from SSD1/MacOS Extended to SSD2/FAT32 (two physically different and internal SATA drives):

- ISO file size: 4.7 GB
- Space available on SSD2 partition: 20 GB

Error message:

> "The item "*.iso" can't be copied because it is too large for the
>   volume's format"

Tried to copy on a USB memory stick (10 GB available): same message.

From the command line:

```
cp /Users/me/file.iso /Volumes/Untitled/  
cp: /Volumes/Untitled/file.iso: File too large
```

Copying on the USB stick, same error but after trying for ten minutes (i.e. it thought the space was available, but it was not).

Everything works when coping a smaller file (40 MB).

What is wrong? I have the impression that the issue is not related to the space available on the destination drive, but to the size of the file being copied.

System details:

- MacBook Pro 17" 2009
- OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 (the latest one I can use)

Comment: Long-term, I'd use ExFAT for cross-platform storage. It doesn't have the 4GB file-size limit & can be read & written by Mac & Win natively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FAT32 has a maximum size for any individual file: 4 GB.

You can split the file into <4 GB segments, copy to the FAT32 disk, then recombine them once you've copied them off the FAT32 disk to somewhere else.

```bash
# make 4 GB file segments
truncate -s 7.8G /path/to/file
split --bytes=3.9GB --numeric-suffixes /path/to/file /path/to/file.part
# copy to disk
cp /path/to/file.part* /Volumes/yourFATdisk/
```

```bash
# copy from disk
cp /Volumes/yourFATdisk/file.part* /path/to/
# combine segments
cat /path/to/file.part* > /path/to/file
```

Adapted from https://superuser.com/questions/440509/getting-around-the-fat32-4gb-file-size-limit

Comment: For future readers, please note that AFAIK, the `truncate` command is for **creating a new file**. If you already have a big file in mind, **don't do it** – you'll lose everything that got truncated, which may corrupt the file!